# NTP: ntpdate to sync time between the PCs on a private network

Tags: linux, time, ntp, synchronization

I have two systems. One acts as Primary/Active and has Internet connection and gets time from NTP server. The second system is Secondary/Passive and has no connection to the external world.

Primary and Secondary are connected on a private network interface `eth1`. Primary has

- IP: 169.254.10.10
- Subnet: 255.255.255.248
- Broadcast: 169.254.10.15

Secondary has

- IP: 169.254.10.11
- Subnet: 255.255.255.248
- Broadcast: 169.254.10.15

Primary has the following ntp.conf Configuration

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable
server 192.168.101.25
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
restrict 169.254.10.0 mask 255.255.255.248
broadcast 169.254.10.15
disable auth
broadcastclient
```

I sync time on Secondary with only ntpdate and do not run ntpd daemon on Secondary. on Secondary I run `ntpdate -b -t 4 -p 4 -u 169.254.10.10` (Primary Interface IP) And Ntpd server is running on Primary with the above said configuration.

The time on Secondary is not updated and throws error `ntpdate[3636]: no server suitable for synchronization found`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ntpdate` does not read the `ntp.conf` file.

To synchronize one-time, pass the IP address of the server on the command line:

```
ntpdate 169.254.10.10
```

Comment: I tried that i still get the same error

`ntpdate 169.254.10.10`

`28 Jul 20:54:03 ntpdate[5452]: no server suitable for synchronization found`

Comment: Is there actually an NTP server at that address, and is there a firewall blocking it?

Comment: Ntp Server runs on 169.254.10.10 that is Primary System (CP1) With the above given configuration.
and I run ntpdate from 169.254.10.11 that is Secondary or redundant system (CP2). 

These two Cps are connected over private 1GB ethernet connection.